# page_cache_maximum_age wrongly set

Tags: caching

In our production server, we wrongly set **page_cache_maximum_age** a long value,

```
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 12960000;
```

Now viewers are complaining they are seeing old contents in there homepage.

I am able to see new contents with a force reload (CTRL + F5).

Is there any way to force the client side to refresh the pages in this stage?

We have our architecture **Drupal+Nginx+Varnish** and **CloudFlare** on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Either you don't need, or you can't:

If this was translated to HTTP header, and browser "knows" not to ask for the page again, nothing you would try to do about it will have any effect, because browser simply won't contact your server anyway, so it will not download any remedy you might try.

If it affected only server-side systems, tuning it down and clearing caches should be enough already, and server shouldn't send "304 Not Modified" to your clients.

Hard to tell which case is it without knowing your caching setup, but I'm afraid "fix it and wait" is the only way either way.

Unless, for some reason, you can identify uncached JS file included on affected pages. This would be a bug, so I don't expect it to happen, but if, it might be a bug you could use - ask for it on Stack Overflow, then, as this is much less Drupal-related.

If your front page isn't cached that way, you can alter all affected links. It will not help people having issues with bookmarked pages, but it will direct regular users to current content.

Comment: Actually I was meant to set max expiry for varnish when Drupal serve the content to varnish. From varnish to user end the max age should be normal or 0, so that selective cache purge will works efficiently. But due to a mistake in varnish vlc it passed the same header to clients.

Comment: @shameem so it's the first case - you can't affect user agent behavior if user agent does not contact you at all.

Comment: yes I understood. :( but we are out of choices that's how I end up here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to flush the entire cache for now with

```
varnishadm "ban req.url ~ /"
```

found this at https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/696
OR

```
 set req.hash_always_miss = true;
```

What you are looking for is to `miss` as stated on https://www.varnish-software.com/book/3/VCL_functions.html and the easiest way is to force the requested cache to not be present

simpeler explaination: [image]